# How can I run an AutoHotKey program on Mac?

Tags: autohotkey

So I just recently programmed a simple AHK GUI for a school project and was wondering if there is any way that I could run it on Mac as well? If not, is there any equivalent program that I could use? It doesn't have to be exactly alike my AHK program, but I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions for how to program a GUI that sends keypresses to the active window and is easily downloadable. Thanks so much. My AHK program can be found below. Sorry for my novice question.

```
#NoEnv
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 99000000
#HotkeyInterval 99000000
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off
Process, Priority, , A
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
SetMouseDelay, -1
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0
SetWinDelay, -1
SetControlDelay, -1
SendMode Input



#singleinstance force
Gui, +alwaysontop
Gui, Color, purple
Gui,Font, s24, Arial Black
Gui, Add, Button, x5 y5 gBuzzer, BUZZ
Gui, Show, x800 y100 w145 h90, Online Certamen Buzzer
Gui +Resize -MaximizeBox  ; Change the settings of the default GUI window.
Gui -MinimizeBox
Return

Buzzer:
{
Send, !{Esc} ; Changed from Alt+Tab
Send, {!}buzz{Enter}
}
Return

Esc::ExitApp
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the BetterTouchTool. But it's not free.
https://folivora.ai/